# Какие есть способы автозапуска программы при старте Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-10

Есть программа которая должна запускаться вместе с Windows чем раньше тем лучше. Но есть ли способы сделать так, кроме как перенести прогу в папку автозапуска?
Вшить в ос, или что-то ещё...

P.S. желательно чтобы это можно было сделать программно например через скрипт питон

Comment: Кстати, сервис или псевдодрайвер запустится раньше, чем программа....

Comment: `nssm` можно ещё попробовать. Не ваниль, но для некоторого круга задач - очень даже вариант.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно добавить пусть к экзешнику в реестр в

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
```

или в

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
```

В чем между ними разница не знаю.

Comment: Как я понимаю (допускаю, не 100% верно), второй вариант лучше для 32-битной программы на 64-битной системе.

Answer (score 4):

Можно создать службу, которая будет стартовать с запуском Windows. Есть такая утилита `sc`. Работать под администратором в `powershell`.

Чтобы создать службу

```
sc create NameOfService binPath="path\to\file.exe" start = auto
```

Чтобы запустить вручную

```
sc start NameOfService
```